# If $s = 4m - 3$, then $\sigma(p^s) = (1 + p^{2m-1})(1 + p + \ldots + p^{2m-2})$. Is there a similar factorization for $\sigma(q^t)$ when $t=4n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, factoring, divisor-sum, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $p,q$ be (odd) primes, and let $m,n,s,t$ be positive integers.

Denote the classical sum of divisors of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.

[M. A. Nyblom](http://www.pphmj.com/abstract/8165.htm) showed that, if $s = 4m - 3$, then we have the simple factorization
$$\sigma(p^s) = (1 + p^{2m-1})(1 + p + \ldots + p^{2m-2}).$$

Here is my inquiry:

> Is there a similar factorization for $\sigma(q^t)$ when $t = 4n$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $t = 4n = 2\cdot{2n}$ is even, then $\sigma(q^t)$ is odd.  Since $q$ is odd, this means that there are an odd number ($= 4n + 1$) of odd terms in
$$\sigma(q^t) = 1 + q + \ldots + q^{4n-1} + q^{4n},$$
which essentially means that we cannot take the terms successively in pairs (i.e. $(1 + q) \nmid \sigma(q^t)$).

Which brings us to the question:  Does $(1 + q + q^2)$ divide $\sigma(q^t)$?

Allow me to consider simpler cases first.

- $t = 4$: $\sigma(q^t) = \sigma(q^4) = 1 + q + q^2 + q^3 + q^4 = (1 + q + q^2) + (q^2 + q^3 + q^4) - q^2 = (q^2 + 1)(1 + q + q^2) - q^2$

Note that $\gcd(q^2,q^2 + 1) = \gcd(q^2, 1 + q + q^2) = 1$ (since $q$ is prime).  Hence,
$$\gcd\bigg(q^2, (q^2 + 1)(1 + q + q^2)\bigg) = 1,$$
which essentially means that $(1 + q + q^2) \nmid \sigma(q^4)$.

- $t = 8$: $\sigma(q^t) = \sigma(q^8) = 1 + q + q^2 + q^3 + q^4 + q^5 + q^6 + q^7 + q^8 = (1 + q + q^2) + {q^3} (1 + q + q^2) + {q^6} (1 + q + q^2)$

Evidently, we then see that $1 + q + q^2$ divides $\sigma(q^8)$.

- $t=12$: $\sigma(q^t) = \sigma(q^{12}) = 1 + q + q^2 + q^3 + q^4 + q^5 + q^6 + q^7 + q^8 + q^9 + q^{10} + q^{11} + q^{12}$
  $= (1 + q + q^2) + {q^3} (1 + q + q^2) + {q^6} (1 + q + q^2) + {q^9} (1 + q + q^2) + q^{12}$

Hence, we "conclude" that $(1 + q + q^2) \nmid \sigma(q^{12})$.

- $t=16$: $\sigma(q^t) = \sigma(q^{16}) = 1 + q + q^2 + q^3 + q^4 + q^5 + q^6 + q^7 + q^8 + q^9 + q^{10} + q^{11} + q^{12} + q^{13} + q^{14} + q^{15} + q^{16}$
  $= (1 + q + q^2) + {q^3} (1 + q + q^2) + {q^6} (1 + q + q^2) + {q^9} (1 + q + q^2) + q^{12} (1 + q + q^2) + q^{15} (1 + q)$

Hence, we "conclude" that $(1 + q + q^2) \nmid \sigma(q^{16})$.

*And then, I will have to consider whether $(1 + q + q^2 + q^3) \mid \sigma(q^t)$, etc.*

**Alas, this is where I get stuck.**

---

I was actually hoping somebody with more (in-depth) knowledge of [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) could explain what is going on here.

Comment: One interpretation of the question is:  "does the polynomial $1 + x + \cdots + x^{4n}$ factor in $\mathbb Z[x]$?"  (If it does, then plugging in $x = q$ gives a factorization of the integer you're interested in.)  The answer to this is "not in general".  In particular, this polynomial is irreducible if (and only if) $4n+1$ is prime, in which case it's a cyclotomic polynomial.  It is divisible by $1 + x + \cdots x^{a-1}$ if and only if $a$ divides $4n+1$, which explains why $1 + q + \cdots + q^{4n}$ is divisible by $1+q+q^2$ iff $3 | (4n+1)$.  And none of this is special to the case $t = 4n$.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @RaviFernando!  Please flesh out your [last comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4400751/if-s-4m-3-then-sigmaps-1-p2m-11-p-ldots-p2m-2?noredirect=1#comment9204873_4400751) as an actual answer so that I can upvote and then accept.  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding my comment into an answer:

One interpretation of the question is:  "does the polynomial $1 + x + \cdots + x^{4n}$ factor in $\mathbb Z[x]$?"  (If it does, then plugging in $x = q$ gives a factorization of the integer you're interested in.)  The theory of cyclotomic polynomials shows that this polynomial is irreducible if and only if $4n+1$ is prime.  Any divisor $a$ of $4n+1$ gives rise to a divisor $1 + x + \cdots + x^{a-1}$ of the polynomial; in particular, the case $a = 3$ accounts for the results of your numerical investigations.

Let me provide some context about cyclotomic polynomials; since this is valid for all positive integers, I'll write $n$ instead of $4n+1$.  The cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_d(x)$ provide the exact factorization of the polynomials $x^n - 1$ (in $\mathbb Z[x]$, or equivalently by Gauss's lemma in $\mathbb Q[x]$) in the following sense:  each $\Phi_d$ is monic and irreducible, and we have $\prod_{d|n} \Phi_d(x) = x^n - 1$.  The relevance of this to your question is that we have:
$$
x^{n-1} + \cdots + x + 1 = \frac{x^n-1}{x-1} = \frac{x^n-1}{\Phi_1(x)} = \prod_{d|n, d \neq 1} \Phi_d(x).
$$
Since the irreducible factors correspond to the divisors $d > 1$ of $n$, this proves my earlier claim that the polynomial is irreducible if and only if $n$ is prime.  You can also see the divisors $1 + x + \cdots + x^{a-1}$ in this picture:  just observe that if $a$ divides $n$, then
$$
\left( \prod_{d|a, d \neq 1} \Phi_d(x) \right) \text{ divides } \left( \prod_{d|n, d \neq 1} \Phi_d(x) \right),
$$
since the index set on the left is a subset of the one on the right.

Lastly, although the prime-indexed cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_p(x) = \frac{x^p - 1}{x-1} = x^{p-1} + \cdots + x + 1$ are all irreducible, it is of course not true that the integer $\Phi_p(q) = q^{p-1} + \cdots + q + 1 = \sigma(q^{p-1})$ will always be prime.  We can, however, say two things in this direction.  First, it will never have any divisors of the form $q^{a-1} + \cdots + q + 1$, since if $p = ak + b$ with $0 < b < a$, then we can explicitly divide $q^{p-1} + \cdots + q + 1$ by $q^{a-1} + \cdots + q + 1$ with remainder, similarly to your calculations:
\begin{align*}
q^{p-1} + \cdots + q + 1 & = \left( q^{a-1} + \cdots + q + 1 \right) \cdot q^b \left( q^{a(k-1)} + \cdots + q^a + 1 \right) \\
& \quad + \left( q^{b-1} + \cdots + q + 1 \right),
\end{align*}
where the remainder $q^{b-1} + \cdots + q + 1$ is positive and less than $q^{a-1} + \cdots + q + 1$.  Second, the Bateman-Horn conjecture implies that every cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$ produces infinitely many prime values $\Phi_n(a)$ with $a \in \mathbb Z$.  Moreover, if $n$ is not a power of $2$, then applying Bateman-Horn to the pair of polynomials $(x, \Phi_n(x))$ implies that $\Phi_n(x)$ even produces infinitely many prime values at prime inputs.  (This isn't true when $n$ is a power of $2$ because $\Phi_{2^k}(x) = x^{2^{k-1}} + 1$ is always even when $x$ is odd.)  So if you are interested in $\sigma(q^{4n})$ when $4n+1$ happens to be prime, you should expect that these numbers genuinely will sometimes be prime.

Comment: My profuse thanks for expanding your comment into a comprehensive answer, @RaviFernando!  Accepting it now.